# What is the aircraft type in the movie 'Once Upon a Time in Hollywood'?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-identification, boeing, aviation-in-fiction

[*Once Upon a Time... in Hollywood*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Hollywood), a recent movie set in the late 1960s, has a few scenes in a [Pan American Airways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am) (Pan Am) aircraft. Looking at Pan Am's [fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_American_World_Airways#Fleet) at that time, it looks like it was either a [Boeing 720B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_720) or a [Boeing 707-320C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_707). What type was it?

I have tried looking for images of the scene but couldn't find any. Hopefully, someone has watched the movie and can answer.

Comment: How would the voters know that an answer is right without a screenshot? And what if there's more than one plane (if you recognized the easily recognizable 747 mentioned in the earlier comment by@PerlDuck, then possibly there's more than one).

Comment: Yes, a screenshot would help, but he's obviously counting on answers from those who have seen the movie...

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but you should include a picture of the aircraft (screenshot of the movies?)

Comment: The first place I checked was the [Internet Movie Plane Database](http://www.impdb.org) but they don't have the movie listed yet.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes as no comment seems to justify downvotes (a missing picture hardly justify a  downvote).

Comment: Internet Movie Plane Database now lists this film, with a screenshot showing a 747 with the tag  "Friday August 8th 1969" - indeed many months before the 747 was introduced. http://impdb.org/index.php?title=Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Hollywood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably a *wrong* B747.

I haven't seen the movie yet but from all I read about it, it contains an airplane scene in which a wrong airplane is shown for the time the film is set. The *Internet Movie Database [(IMDB)](https://www.imdb.com)* lists two [goofs](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7131622/goofs) (movie errors) related to aircraft in that [movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7131622/):

> Pan Am did not introduce the Boeing 747 until 
>   January, 1970, over five months after the 
>   Tate murders.
>   [(source)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7131622/goofs?item=gf4651208)

and

> When showing the 747 model in at least one of the 
>   flight scenes, the wrong model was shown. A model 
>   of a 747-800 series (with some of the windows edited 
>   out) was used. The 800 series didn't fly until 
>   the 2000's. 
>   [(source)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7131622/goofs?item=gf4654658)

Sometimes the [trivia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7131622/trivia) section also lists some information like *The plane at 32:00 was a G5* but as of now there's no such hint for this movie and the B747 is just a guess because it is the only aircraft mentioned in the context of this film.